# global variable read/write access

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I need to access (read/write) some variables in all of my views.

The variables will be defined in view 1, then used and set to a new value in view 2.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya , there is much a easy way to handle this.....

You can take a Global Variable

In your Delegate.h file declare your variable:

```
@interface Smoke_ApplicationAppDelegate : NSObject {

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;
NSString *messageString;  //This would be your String Variable
} @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *messageString;
```

Secondly in Delegate.m file

```
@implementation Smoke_ApplicationAppDelegate

@synthesize window; @synthesize navigationController; @synthesize messageString; //
```

Synthesize it over here..

This is Done .Now you can use this String Variable in All/any class you want..

To use this Global Variable.

Just import you Delegate file make the obj of it....

```
import "DelegateFile.h"

@implementation About

DelegateFile *appDel;
```

Now in Your class.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];

appDel=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

}
```

Now you can access it anywhere in your class by this Object:

```
appDel.messageString
```

Just follow my Steps Carefully After giving so much pain to my finger, I am sure this is definitely going to help you.....

Have a easy life,

Comment: hey i endet op using the variables made in the delegate file because i can't the the other whys to work :-(

Comment: still there are ways to do the same thing without having the delegate.But if you want to use that variable in more than 2 view controllers then prefer to have the delegate. :) Do you want the other way for this too ??

Answer (score 0):

Please don't declare them as instance variables on your application delegate, it's not really good design practice for MVC.

Your best option is to create a shared data model. This can be what is called a 'singleton' class so there is only every 1 instance of it. This model class can then store any central information that is needed by various views.

Rob Napier's answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410830/apple-singleton-example-query) is a good reference as are other links from that page. In particular I'd commend [Mike Ash's post here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html).

'Singletons' are great. They encapsulate the data in a model class where it belongs and avoid creeping global variables which make code less easy to decouple in future.

Comment: Singletons are great, and the app delegate is one.  One instance is created and shared across the lifetime of the application.  The only real difference between the two approaches is that adding a new singleton class better handles cases where there is tight coupling between a group of state variables.  If the variables are all unrelated to each other then it doesn't really matter where you stick them.  Either you clutter the built-in singleton, you clutter the project with a bunch of trivial singleton classes, or you clutter a single new singleton with a bunch of unrelated variables.