# How to pass the Value from UITextField from one VC to a string in another VC?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have googled for this and even tried searching in many forums, also tried Singleton, etc but each time my 2nd VC'c string is returning a NULL value.

RETRIEVALTVC is my VC in which I'm expecting for the value and IRTViewController is my VC having the TextField.

I have imported all the header files.

This is my RetrievalTVC

RetrievalTVC.h

```
#import<UIKit>
NSString *string;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
```

In RetrievalTVC.m when I tried to read the value of string its returning NULL

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[self list];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)list{
  NSLog(@"Value of string: %@",string);
}
```

This is my IRTViewController

IRTViewConroller.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchTrain;
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender //Action when Button is Pressed
```

IRTViewController.m

```
-(IBAciton)search:(id)sender{
RetrievalTVC *retrieve = [[RetrievalTVC alloc]init];
retrieve.string = searchTrain.text;
//Here when i used NSLog its returning the value
```

Please Help.. Millions Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you pushing `retriv` into the view heirarchy Saarumaan?

Comment: I mean like `[self.navigationController pushViewController:retriv animated:yes];`

Comment: So the value is not being passed then...

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the property of the string in Retrieval class or allocated it?

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not initialized.

Initialize it in your init of RetrievalTVC.m. It will solve the error.

Better make it a property.

**Edit: do this .**

RetrievalTVC.h

```
#import<UIKit>
@interface

   NSString *string;//comment this line ..this line is not required.
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;

@end
```

RetrievalTVC.m

```
#import"RetrievalTVC.h"

@implementation

@synthesize string;
// memory management

    - (void) dealloc
    {
    [super dealloc];
    [self.string release];
    }
```

and update this in your your existing code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad]; // the list method is not required
}
```

Now it will work

Comment: cant comment out the LIST method coz i'm needing it, to execute rest of the code..

Comment: you on Skype?..i can't add you to chat

Comment: I got the problem.. My RetrivalTVC was getting loaded first and then the IRTViewController, dont know how but.. So i copy paste the code in a new Project and its working fine now..
Thanx a lot..

Comment: lol...;) nice you got it by yourself..you just gained experience..but don't stop here..search why it was loading first by breakpointing and debugging your code..

Comment: Ya for sure... cheers.. got it finally.. :) will debug n get it done... Thanx a loads again.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create property in `RetrievalTVC` like :

**RetrievalTVC.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *string;
```

and synthesis it in **RetrievalTVC.m** file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `retrieve`'s scope maybe wrong.

```
-(IBAciton)search:(id)sender{
RetrievalTVC *retrieve = [[RetrievalTVC alloc]init];
retrieve.string = searchTrain.text;
//Here when I used NSLog its returning the value 
NSLog(@"%@",retriv.string);
```

If this is right, you should check your code where you use `retrieve.string`

Maybe this `retrieve` is not equal that `retrieve`.

Comment: retriv  is a local variable here. So it will not be accessed to other VC. And yes its returning value here. But when i'm trying to read the value of string in RetrivalTVC there i'm getting NULL.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing in **synthesizing the variable RetrievalTVC.m** class file.

Change the property from :

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
```

to:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;
```

If all of solutions doesn't work , then why don't you prefer doing it using the delegate variable i.e Global.

Just check out this, it will solve your problem :

[global variable read/write access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442352/434898)

Comment: I did the steps which u mentioned in that post but again the same NULL value is returned.. :(

Comment: are you sure you did appDel=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; in your ViewDidLoad method ?And also, try to print searchTrain.text value before assigning to any other variable.Just make sure it retain its value.

Comment: searchTrain.text is printing the value.. But i want the value in another VC where its returning NULL..

Comment: @saarumann There is no need to alloc the String. It;s creating the problem since it allocates news memory.

Comment: Ajay, i put NSLog in two places..  And my console is showing the value of NSLog of List first and then the NSLog of Search.. So i'm getting a feel that its first reading the value of LIST and then SEARCH.. Am i right.? and if yes what should i do.? I have updated the code, please take a look..

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code like this.

RetrievalTVC.h

```
#import<UIKit>
NSString *string;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
-(IBAction)getValue:(NSString *)val;
```

In RetrievalTVC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[self list];
}

-(IBAction)getValue:(NSString *)val
{

   string=val;
   NSLog(@"Value of string: %@",string);
}

- (NSMutableArray *)list{
string = [[NSString alloc]init];
 NSLog(@"Value of string: %@",string);
}
```

IRTViewConroller.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchTrain;
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender //Action when Button is Pressed
```

IRTViewController.m

```
-(IBAciton)search:(id)sender{
RetrievalTVC *retriv = [[RetrievalTVC alloc]init];
[retrieve getValue:searchTrain.text];
retrieve.string = searchTrain.text;
```

Comment: I want to fetch value from UITextField in one ViewController and send it to another ViewController. But its returning NULL in another ViewController.

Comment: Create Event in secondViewController like -(IBAction)GetValue:(NSString *)val; than Call it in .m File at that time your value is in  val variable..Also you need to call this event from where you are redirecting the view...Got it??

Answer (score 0):

use `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;` instead of `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;`

also use `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchTrain;` instead `@property (week, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchTrain

Ok i found the error

don't need to `alloc` string in `viewDidLoad`. what happens here you are setting value in string the push the view then `viewDidLoad` calls and it reallocate it and thus the value is nil

Comment: same thing is happening again... :(

Comment: I did but again the same NULL thing..
Ishu i had a query..
i put NSLog in two places.. And my console is showing the value of NSLog of List first and then the NSLog of Search.. So i'm getting a feel that its first reading the value of LIST and then SEARCH.. Am i right.? and if yes what should i do.? I have updated the code, please take a look.

Comment: which vc on top of navigation stack. and r u using push or presentModelView controller for showing RetrivalTVC

Comment: its IRTViewController on top of navigation stack and no im not using push or presentModelView..

Comment: when button is pressed on first view second view is getting loaded..
UI is working fine.. but the console is showing this kinda output..

Answer (score 0):

Method Names may spelled wrong

Understanding

- IRTViewController - It has text filed, this value need to
  pass to RETRIEVALTVC.

Case 1. RETRIEVALTVC has an object of IRTViewController, Use delegates.
Case 2. When user Tap on button only you will create RETRIEVALTVC in IRTViewController.

Case 1 solution:

RetrievalTVC.h

```
#import<UIKit>
NSString *string;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
```

RetrievalTVC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[self list];
IRTViewController * iRTViewController = [[IRTViewController alloc] init];
iRTViewController.target = self;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)list{
string = [[NSString alloc]init];
 NSLog(@"Value of string: %@",string);
}
```

IRTViewConroller.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchTrain;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id target;
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender //Action when Button is Pressed
```

IRTViewController.m

```
@synthesize target;

-(IBAciton)search:(id)sender{
RetrievalTVC *retrieve =target;
retrieve.string = searchTrain.text;
}
```

Case 2: It has to work with your approach

Comment: Sanjeev..
I did but the same NULL thing..i had a query.. i put NSLog in two places.. And my console is showing the value of NSLog of List first and then the NSLog of Search.. So i'm getting a feel that its first reading the value of LIST and then SEARCH.. Am i right.? and if yes what should i do.? Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In the same line of code that you alloc the new viewController is where you should make assignments (=).

i.e.      in VC1 lets say string = VC1String and in VC2 lets say string = VC2String.

inside the VC1.m, in the same line of code that you allocate VC2 (assuming the allocated name is VC2 as well), just write:

```
VC2.VC2String = VC1String;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,make a nsstring property in Appdelegate class and synthesize it. for example-

In Appdelegate.h:-

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)nsstring *objString;
```

In Appdelegate.m:-

```
@synthesize objString;
```

Now, in the ViewController in which you are entering your string value,do the follwing:-

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
   Appdelegate *obj = (Appdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

obj.objString = Your String;
}
```

Now you can retrieve the value of your string in any view controller class u want.

just make object "obj" using that same code

```
Appdelegate *obj = (Appdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

and then just do

```
RetrievingString = obj.objString;
```

In this way, you can easily retrieve your string value.